# What is the need of reference in C++

Tags: c++

Somebody ask me this question today .
What is the need of reference in C++, why did `Bjarne Stroustrup` thought about `reference` in C++.

Comment: How's "syntactic sugar" rates on the scale of answer's usefulness? Another name for that feature could have been "pointer de-uglifier".

Comment: To have a uniform syntax for accessing a value and a pointer. The most important functionality references fill is the ability to overload operators involving them.

Comment: Your grammar is off. It's hard to tell exactly what you even mean. Are you referring to passing an argument by reference as opposed to passing by value or by pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is Stroustrup explanation : http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#pointers-and-references

> C++ inherited pointers from C, so I couldn't remove them without causing serious compatibility problems. References are useful for several things, but the direct reason I introduced them in C++ was to support operator overloading.

Here is an example :

```
void f1(const complex* x, const complex* y) // without references
{
    complex z = *x+*y;  // ugly
    // ...
}

void f2(const complex& x, const complex& y) // with references
{
    complex z = x+y;    // better
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `complex a, b; f1 (&a, &b); f2 (a, b);` Calling the function is much less strenuous as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the answer to questions like this, read a book called "The Design and Evolution of C++", by the man himself:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/dne.html

Alternatively, see here, where he explains the answer in detail:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#pointers-and-references

To quote:

> C++ inherited pointers from C, so I couldn't remove them without
>   causing serious compatibility problems. References are useful for
>   several things, but the direct reason I introduced them in C++ was to
>   support operator overloading. For example:

```
void f1(const complex* x, const complex* y) // without references
{
    complex z = *x+*y;  // ugly
    // ...
}

void f2(const complex& x, const complex& y) // with references
{
    complex z = x+y;    // better
    // ...
}
```